# NSLocalizedString Problem- Localization of a variable that holds a string

Tags: ios4, localization, nslocalizedstring

```
//Viewcontroller.m code
NSLocalizedString(@"attributes",@"Attribute Name")

//Localizable.string code
"attributes"="attributes-french";
```

This method works great for localization of @"attributes"

Now what should be the code if I want to use a variable

I am using

```
//Viewcontroller.m code
NSString *Value=@"attributes"
NSLocalizedString(Value,@"Attribute Name"); 

//Localizable.string code
"Value"="Value-french";
```

This is not working. Can someone tell me the correct way of using NSLocalizdString for localizing a variable (that holds a string)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot localize on a variable name. You only localize on the value held by the variable. So your `Localizable.strings` should contain,

```
"attributes"="attributes-french"
```

If anything, you can vary portions of the string using `%@` as described [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-99832).

Answer (score 0):

There's not a problem with the `NSLocalizedString` call, but rather, the definition in your *Localizable.strings* file.

Since you define the variable `Value` as "attributes", that is what the function will use as a key to look up the correct localized string.

This should work correctly:

```
//Viewcontroller.m code
NSString *Value=@"attributes"
NSLocalizedString(Value,@"Attribute Name"); 

//Localizable.string code
"attributes"="Value-french";
```

I tested similar code in Swift, which then looked like this:

```
//Viewcontroller.swift code
let Value="attributes"
NSLocalizedString(Value, comment:"Attribute Name")

//Localizable.string code
"attributes"="Value-french"; // <- don't forget the semicolon!
```